# How do I disable persistence (caching) for firestore on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set `isPersistenceEnabled = NO` for firestore in the GoogleService-Info.plist file I imported into my react-native file.

I tried setting to
`IS_PERSISTENCE_ENABLED = NO`, however I can still see that firestore is pulling from the local cache. What is the proper way to disable this setting?

Answer (score 3):

This is described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence):

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false

// Any additional options
// ...

let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.settings = settings
```

There's no option in the configuration plist for this.  You have to configure persistence with code.

Comment: How to do that with the v9 modular API?